# PHP/Drupal - Pound sign on array

Tags: php, drupal

Hi
When I print out the variable, I got pound sign on the array as below:

```
...
[#weight] => 0
[#theme] => text_formatter_default
[#field_name] => field_product_item_no
[#type_name] => product
...
```

What is the meaning of Pound sign?

Thanks

Comment: can you show the input of this array???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is just the [way the Drupal Forms API expects its data](http://drupal.org/node/751826).

Comment: so I can say that this is just the coding style of Drupal?

Comment: @Charles Yes, it's just how it's done in Drupal when you're dealing with form fields.

Comment: I believe that the '#' indicates a user-changeable property, like '#id' in a form element. It also allows you to use your own property that has a key like 'name' without a conflict with the existing '#name'

Answer (score 2):

In Drupal, [#key]'s value is metadata, whereas [key]'s value is data.

According to the answer given to [my question about "#" properties](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/33227/what-are-properties) on the Drupal Stackexchange,

> Put simply, array keys in a render array without a # in front of the name are seen as children of the render array, and are subsequently rendered themselves (recursively).
>
> Those with a # in front of theme are seen as meta data/variables for the render array to use as necessary, and are not themselves rendered.

Answer (score 1):

The pound sign is just a valid character as array key and has no special meaning in PHP besides a convention defined by the application.