# Meaning of # in variables

Tags: drupal

I was looking at some module code:

$element['location_settings'] = array(
  '#type' => 'value',
  '#value' => $element['#location_settings'],
);

What is the meaning of # in #location_settings
And i'm unsure whether $element['#location_settings'] is a form element or just a regular variable in this case.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP/Drupal - Pound sign on array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6040724/php-drupal-pound-sign-on-array)

Comment: It's just a naming convention Drupal uses.

Comment: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/33227/what-are-properties

Answer (score 1):

In the Drupal FAPI all variables (keys), that starts with '#' treated as properties/data of the current node, all other variables treated as children nodes. This is just a FAPI convention.

So, $element['#location_settings'] can't be children form element, only regular variable.

Answer (score 0):

'#' is for Drupal theming, Drupal will read those variables for theming hook. These variable are not general, it means nothing if not passed into form function or theming function.